# Change the [channels]

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

There are two tags:

- [channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/channels)
- [django-channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-channels)

A lot of questions about [django-channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-channels) have the tag [channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/channel).

What is right, what is wrong?

Comment: [channel] seems to be a candidate for burnination. It doesn't have a description and it's used for totally different things: color channels, go channels, django channels, youtube channels...